# Does there exist $r \in (0,1)$ such that $T(sx) \geq s^{r}T(x)$ for all $s \in (0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

For real numbers $b \geq a \geq 0$ and $p \geq 1,$ let
$$T(x) = \left[2b^p - (2a-x)^p\right]^{1/p}.$$
Does there exist a real number $r \in (0,1)$ such that $T(sx) \geq s^r T(x)$ for all $s \in (0,1)$ and $2a \geq x\geq 0$ ?

Comment: Under the conditions $T$ may not always be real, take $p=2, a=5, b=6$ then $T(1)=3i$.